# Jdeveloper can't change table in query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jcombobox

I have created a method that takes a table name from a jcombobox and inserts it to a query so that users may search the selected table. The problem is that when I change the selected table from "people" to "informants" for example, the query stays on "people"...

Here is my code:

```
   private String box_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            String selected = box.getSelectedItem().toString();


            System.out.println(selected);
            return null;

                }

 public String getSelectedTable(){

 return box.getSelectedItem().toString();
 } 


    private  void button_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {
        DataHandler dh = new DataHandler();
        ResultSet rset;


        try {
            rset = dh.getAllEmployees();
            while (rset.next())
        {
        area.append(rset.getInt(1) + " " + rset.getString(2) + " " + rset.getString(3)+ "\n");
            }
        } catch (SQLException f) {
        }

    }
 }
```

**The button calls the DataHandler().getAllEmployees()

Here is the code for the DataHandler()**

```
        public ResultSet getAllEmployees() throws SQLException{

                GUI ins = new GUI();
                getDBConnection(); 

                stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

                query = "SELECT * FROM " + ins.getSelectedTable() + " ORDER BY id";
                System.out.println("\nExecuting query: " + query);
                rset = stmt.executeQuery(query); 
                return rset;

            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814524/jdeveloper-cant-change-the-table-name

Comment: instead of answering the question... you criticize it.. nice!

Comment: You have post 2 questions with partial code neither of which fully describe problem. Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for better help sooner